# Joi validation with 2 mandatory fields and 1mandatory among any 3 keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

I need to write joi validation for the payload like

```
{ a,b,c,d,e}
```

In which a and b are required and at least any of the remaining 3 is required

Like

```
{a,b,c}
```

or

```
{a,b,d}
```

or

```
{a,b,e}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Joi.object()
    .keys({
      a: Joi.string()
        .required(),
      b: Joi.string()
        .email()
        .required(),
      c: Joi.string()
        .optional(),
      d: Joi.string()
        .optional(),
      e: Joi.string()
        .optional()
    })
    .or(“c”, “d”, “e”).required()
};